# MVC4 Routing Subfolder Directory for Checkout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, routeconfig

What do I need to do to map these URLs to my routes?

```
example.com/checkout?o=1234
example.com/checkout/shipping?o=1234
example.com/checkout/payment?o=1234
example.com/checkout/review?o=1234
example.com/checkout/receipt?o=1234
```

In the RouteConfig, I have these defined:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Checkout",
         url: "checkout",
         defaults: new { controller = "Checkout", action = "Index", o = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );

 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "checkout Prefix",
          url: "Checkout/{controller}/{action}/{o}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Shipping|Payment|Review|Receipt", action = "Index", o = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
```

The controller folders are:

```
 Controllers
      CheckoutController.cs
            Checkout
                 ShippingController.cs
                 PaymentController.cs
                 ReviewController.cs
                 ReceiptController.cs
```

When I switch the order and but the Checkout Prefix first, it messes up the "checkout?o=" route. When I put the Checkout route first, the second never gets hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that `o` is part of the route is incorrect. Query strings are not evaluated as part of the match.

Also, you should be specifying the regular expression in a constraint, not as a default value.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Checkout",
    url: "checkout",
    defaults: new { controller = "Checkout", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "checkout Prefix",
    url: "checkout/{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { controller = "Shipping|Payment|Review|Receipt" }
);
```